# I can't find which variable to use of the if statement

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, variables

I want to make a project when you finish clicking 10 times (to 0) it opens a new window.

The code is here:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
public class game implements ActionListener{
    static int count = 10;
    static JLabel label = new JLabel("" + count, SwingConstants.CENTER);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        
    
        JButton button = new JButton("Click me!");
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(500, 400);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        frame.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new game());
        
        frame.setVisible(true);

        if(count == 0) {
            count = 100;
            label.setText(count + "");
            JFrame win_frame = new JFrame();
            JLabel win_label = new JLabel("You win!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
            win_frame.add(win_label);
            win_frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            win_frame.setSize(500, 400);
            win_frame.setVisible(true);
        }
        
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        label.setText("" + count--);
        
    }

}
```

and I don't know which variable to use for the if statement. Should I use `count`, `label`(I can't make it support an int) or make a new variable?

Comment: You've done well. All you have to do is move the `if` statement into the `actionPerformed()` method. The reason is because the counter's state is only important upon each click - and the `actionPerformed()` method is where you will react to that click. Have fun!

Comment: Additionally, I would consider moving the `actionPerformed()` to it's own class that implements `ActionListener`. Otherwise, you are creating two instances of your game in memory and I doubt that is your intent.